# Using VBA for a cycle loop between sheets of an excel file

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy-paste

I'm very new to VBA and have a question. Sorry if it sounds really basic. I will appreciate any help. I have an excel file having 9 sheets (Names: Total, 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21). First, I want to copy the second row of each sheet in order from sheets "0", "3", "6", "9", "12", "15", "18", "21" and paste them in rows "A2:X2" to "A9:X9" of sheet "Total". Then I want to repeat this with third rows, fourth rows, until the 365th row.

The most simple code for the first two sections will be like this but I want to write it like a loop using (for) or any other things to make it easy to use.

```
Sub Copy_rows()
' copying the second rows:
Worksheets("0").Range("A2:X2").Copy Worksheets("Total").Range("A2:X2")
Worksheets("3").Range("A2:X2").Copy Worksheets("Total").Range("A3:X3")
Worksheets("6").Range("A2:X2").Copy Worksheets("Total").Range("A4:X4")
Worksheets("9").Range("A2:X2").Copy Worksheets("Total").Range("A5:X5")
Worksheets("12").Range("A2:X2").Copy Worksheets("Total").Range("A6:X6")
Worksheets("15").Range("A2:X2").Copy Worksheets("Total").Range("A7:X7")
Worksheets("18").Range("A2:X2").Copy Worksheets("Total").Range("A8:X8")
Worksheets("21").Range("A2:X2").Copy Worksheets("Total").Range("A9:X9")

'Copying the third rows:
Worksheets("0").Range("A3:X3").Copy Worksheets("Total").Range("A10:X10")
Worksheets("3").Range("A3:X3").Copy Worksheets("Total").Range("A11:X11")
Worksheets("6").Range("A3:X3").Copy Worksheets("Total").Range("A12:X12")
Worksheets("9").Range("A3:X3").Copy Worksheets("Total").Range("A13:X13")
Worksheets("12").Range("A3:X3").Copy Worksheets("Total").Range("A14:X14")
Worksheets("15").Range("A3:X3").Copy Worksheets("Total").Range("A15:X15")
Worksheets("18").Range("A3:X3").Copy Worksheets("Total").Range("A16:X16")
Worksheets("21").Range("A3:X3").Copy Worksheets("Total").Range("A17:X17")

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Logic**

1. Look for trends. For example worksheet names.. `0`-`3`-`6`...`21`. It increments by `3`.
2. Rows numbers are fixed. `2` To `365`
3. Instead of copying in a loop, store the values in an array and then output the array in one go. It will be **SUPERFAST**.
4. There are `364` rows, `24` columns per sheet and `8` sheets in total. So you need `364 * 8` row array with `24` columns to store the data.

**Code**

Try this. This code took **less than a second** to run.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim Ar As Variant
    Dim TotalRows As Long
    
    '~~> 364 rows per sheet * 8 sheets
    TotalRows = 364 * 8
    ReDim Ar(1 To TotalRows, 1 To 24)
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim rw As Long: rw = 1
    
    '~~> Loop through the rows
    For j = 2 To 365
        '~~> Loop through 8 worksheets from 0 to 21
        For i = 0 To 21 Step 3
            '~~> Loop through the columns
            For k = 1 To 24
                Ar(rw, k) = Worksheets(CStr(i)).Cells(j, k).Value
            Next k
            '~~> Increment row in array
            rw = rw + 1
      
        Next i
    Next j
    
    '~~> Output to total worksheet
    Worksheets("Total").Range("A2").Resize(UBound(Ar), 24).Value = Ar
End Sub
```

To test, I used this [Sample File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ryf6o782ehz2wo/Amin%20Example.xlsm?dl=0). Run the code `Sample` in `Module1`

Comment: @Amin Could you mark this answer as "accepted answer" if it solves your problem.

Comment: Yes. Thanks to Siddharth it worked great. I made it the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

As-salamualaikum, Amin;

This is a great platform & you are always welcome here.

I hope I have understood your problem correctly, here is the code for your specific problem.

```
Sub copyData()

    Dim mySheets As Variant, r As Long, _
        sh As Variant, lastRow As Long
    
    mySheets = Array("0", "3", "6", "9", "12", "15", "18", "21")
    
    lastRow = 2
    
    For r = 2 To 365
        For Each sh In mySheets
            sheets(sh).Range("A" & r & ":X" & r).Copy _
                sheets("total").Cells(lastRow, 1)
            lastRow = sheets("total").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Next sh
    Next r

End Sub
```

I have tried to keep the code as simple as possible for you. happy coding ...

Comment: Salam. Thank you you very much. It worked perfectly. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim Index As Integer

    Index = 2
    For i = 2 To 365
        Worksheets("0").Range("A" & i & ":X" & i).Copy(Worksheets("Total").Range("A" & Index & ":X" & Index))
        Worksheets("3").Range("A" & i & ":X" & i).Copy(Worksheets("Total").Range("A" & Index + 1 & ":X" & Index + 1))
        Worksheets("6").Range("A" & i & ":X" & i).Copy(Worksheets("Total").Range("A" & Index + 2 & ":X" & Index + 2))
        Worksheets("9").Range("A" & i & ":X" & i).Copy(Worksheets("Total").Range("A" & Index + 3 & ":X" & Index + 3))
        Worksheets("12").Range("A" & i & ":X" & i).Copy(Worksheets("Total").Range("A" & Index + 4 & ":X" & Index + 4))
        Worksheets("15").Range("A" & i & ":X" & i).Copy(Worksheets("Total").Range("A" & Index + 5 & ":X" & Index + 5))
        Worksheets("18").Range("A" & i & ":X" & i).Copy(Worksheets("Total").Range("A" & Index + 6 & ":X" & Index + 6))
        Worksheets("21").Range("A" & i & ":X" & i).Copy(Worksheets("Total").Range("A" & Index + 7 & ":X" & Index + 7))
        Index = Index + i + 5
    Next
```

Comment: No. This is not right. Firstly this method will be tooooo slow. Secondly your code will not give you the desired result PLUS it will error out with `Overflow` since you declared `Index as Integer`. To test it, simply comment the lines starting with `Worksheets...` and try running the code.

Comment: Didn't work unforetunately. I got overflow error.

Comment: Try changing Index to Long

Comment: @SiddharthRout I cannot get it why declaring the index as integer ending up with Overflow.  Does not it have a max value of 2147483647 ?

Comment: Integer in VBA maxes out around 32000